# Complex CAML query

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008, caml

I'm new to CAML type queries. I'm trying to integrate sharepoint calendar data into a SSRS report. I pretty much need to do the following WHERE clause

(EventDate <= @StartDate AND EndDate >= @EndDate) OR (EventDate >= @StartDate AND EndDate <= @EndDate)

I need to include times into it as well. Can anyone please help me - as everything I have tried hasnt given the desired results.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While many of us would be happy to help answer your question, we are much more likely to understand the problem and provide a solution if you show us what you've already tried.

Comment: I'm not sure how to upload what code I have tried, but I've tried using <And> and <Or>, using <Geq> and <Leq> - but what I've tried hasnt given the desired results.

Comment: What is the output, and how does it differ from your intended output?